# Use materialize errors within Simple Form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Materialize uses a a data-error attribute of the label to place the error message in if a form field does not validate. By setting the class of the input to invalid, the error is being shown.

No I'm breaking my head on how to get the following HTML structure with simple_form:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="email" type="email" class="validate invalid">
  <label for="email" data-error="this is where the error should be placed" data-success="right" class="active">Email</label>
</div>
```

The class of input is easy, but how do I set the data-error attribute, without the need to configure each label?